# Determine column data types in a csv and then create a table and insert values from that csv into that table

Tags: python, csv

I am new to Python and struggling to find where the issue is in the code that I am using to:

1. Determine data types and exact length of the columns in the CSV
2. Create table with the column names, data types with correct length extracted from above code
3. Insert the data into SQL Server with the CSV that is being used.

Has someone any experience with this type of problem? Below is the initial code that I have been using but cant even get to determine the right data types and their lengths. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import csv, ast, psycopg2

f = open('/path/to/survey/data/survey_data.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter='|')

longest, headers, type_list = [], [], []


def dataType(val, current_type):
    try:
        # Evaluates numbers to an appropriate type, and strings an error
        t = ast.literal_eval(val)
    except ValueError:
        return 'varchar'
    except SyntaxError:
        return 'varchar'
    if type(t) in [int, datetime, float]:
       if (type(t) in [int, long]) and current_type not in ['float', 'varchar',datetime]:
           # Use smallest possible int type
           if (-32768 < t < 32767) and current_type not in ['int', 'bigint']:
               return 'smallint'
            elif (-2147483648 < t < 2147483647) and current_type not in ['bigint']:
               return 'int'
            else:
               return 'bigint'
      if type(t) is float and current_type not in ['varchar','datetime']:
           return 'decimal'
if type(t) is datetime and current_type not in ['varchar']:
    else:
        return 'varchar'

for row in reader:
    if len(headers) == 0:
        headers = row
        for col in row:
            longest.append(0)
            type_list.append('')
    else:
        for i in range(len(row)):
            # NA is the csv null value
            if type_list[i] == 'varchar' or row[i] == 'NA':
                pass
            else:
                var_type = dataType(row[i], type_list[i])
                type_list[i] = var_type
        if len(row[i]) > longest[i]:
            longest[i] = len(row[i])
f.close()
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what you've tried and what parts did and didn't work? Is the pipe-delimited file consistent enough for strongly-typed database columns?

Comment: Thanks Fred for your response. The code was able to read the csv file correctly as i can see the those column names printed in the the exact same order as in the csv. Pipe delimiter is not a problem. Problem is when i see the create statement printed i do see something like this below:

Comment: create table xxx(name  , dob    ) I dont see the data types with their length printed in the create statement

Comment: Have you confirmed that the values in the `longest` and `type_list` arrays are correct after the file has been completely scanned?

Comment: I printed type_list values and I see all blanks except for the last column. It is just printing varchar(length) for the last column.

Comment: Sounds like your code could use some debug logging statements to show which code branches are and aren't being executed